# Escapar CDATA dentro de otro CDATA en XML

Tags: xml

tengo un XML dentro de un CDATA, necesito saber como escapar los CDATA de dentro, de forma que el padre no se corte al cerrar el primer hijo.

```
<![CDATA[
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <API>
           <PARAMETRO1><![CDATA[TEXTO]]></PARAMETRO1>
           <PARAMETRO2><![CDATA[TEXTO]]></PARAMETRO2>
           <PARAMETRO3><![CDATA[TEXTO]]></PARAMETRO3>
       </API>
]]>
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la especificación, no se puede escapar ([*W3C 2.7 CDATA Sections*](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect)).

Lo que sí se puede hacer es cerrar la sección CDATA actual con los caracteres `]]` y volver a abrir una nueva que incluya al `>`, de modo que se reemplazaría:

```
]]>
```

por

```
]]]]><![CDATA[>
```

---

En tu ejemplo:

```
<![CDATA[
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <API>
           <PARAMETRO1><![CDATA[TEXTO]]]]><![CDATA[></PARAMETRO1>
           <PARAMETRO2><![CDATA[TEXTO]]]]><![CDATA[></PARAMETRO2>
           <PARAMETRO3><![CDATA[TEXTO]]]]><![CDATA[></PARAMETRO3>
       </API>
]]>
```